# Get Max value from the sum of several columns from several data ranges

Tags: sql, max

Thanks for reading and helping in advance-

I'll try to get this across as clearly and concisely as possible;  I have 3 tables for the amount of work each person did in each area (area1, area2, area3).  Each table has a name column, amount column, and date column.

So looking at all three tables as a sum, I want to know the MAX work each person has done from Friday thru Thursday as far as I can go back with the data.  For example, from Friday thru Thursday last week, David did a total of 64 tickets in all three areas, but in the previous Friday thru Thursday period, he did 100 tickets.  Therefore, his MAX is 100-the most he ever did.

Thank you

Comment: What platform are you using? is this SQL Server?

Comment: You need to take a look at the analytics functions in the database? For Sql-Server [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.100).aspx) is the link.

Comment: The tables and data are in an Access 2010 Database.